# IntelliJ Plugin - getting all the files where LookupElement (JS/TS) is defined

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am implementing a plugin for filtering TS/JS completions, where I access CompletionResult element withing filtering function inside CompletionContributor

```
result.runRemainingContributors(parameters) { lookupElement ->
    // get file
    println(lookupElement.lookupElement.psiElement?.containingFile?.containingFile.printToString())
    // get directory
    println(lookupElement.lookupElement.psiElement?.containingFile?.containingDirectory.printToString())
    // here I need all the possible locations of all files where element is located

}
```

This works well when there is only one instance of given symbol, however this way ever gets only one location regardless of how many times it is declared within codebase.

Is there any way to get all the possible locations where such a symbol is located?

How is it decided that given symbol is assigned particular containing file while rest files are ignored?